# While loop not working according to the condition in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to build a Number guessing game which has a while loop with 2 conditions in it. However even after 1 of those 2 conditions become false then also the loop keeps going on even though I have || operator between those conditions. Also if I clear out the first condition of while loop then the second one works just perfectly as I want it to but if it is present then idk why it doesn't stop. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGuess {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Random num = new Random();
    int number = 1 + num.nextInt(10);
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean guessed = false;
    System.out.println("Welcome to Number guess!");
    int guess_count = 5;

    while(guessed == false || guess_count > 0 ) {
        System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
        int input = inp.nextInt();

        if(input == number) {
            System.out.println("You guessed it right!");
            guessed = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Nope!");
            guessed = false;
            guess_count--;
            System.out.println("Guesses left: " + guess_count);
        }
    }


}
}
```

When counter goes below 0 then also the loop keeps going on but I don't want it to.
Please tell me where am I wrong.

Comment: If I understood what you want to achieve correctly, I think you should be using && (not ||).

Comment: You need to better clarify the behavior that you expect. To exit the loop, you need that both `guessed` is `true` and `guess_count` is zero or less. If the last guess was wrong, you set `guessed` to false (in the `else` branch), and thus you will stay in the loop even if `guess_count` is zero or less. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Franco, thanks I now got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an *OR operator*. What you need is an *AND operator*. Means your condition should be `(guessed == false && guess_count > 0 )`.

**WHY?**

Because the *OR* conditional operator works if either the condition is true, in your case if the user unable to guess 5 times then your `guessed` variable is still false while your `guess_count` is less than zero, so your one condition is true. The *AND* operator checks for both the condition.

Comment: @Anonymous you're welcome! Keep learning and happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider modifying your loop like this:

```
        while(guess_count > 0 ) {
            System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
            int input = inp.nextInt();

            if(input == number) {
                System.out.println("You guessed it right!");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Nope!");
                guessed = false;
                guess_count--;
                System.out.println("Guesses left: " + guess_count);
            }
        }
```

OR just modify you condition like this:

```
while(!guessed && guess_count > 0 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition of your while loop should be changed from an OR `||` to an AND `&&`. Currently, the `||` will allow execution if either `guessed == false` OR  `guess_count > 0`. Only one of these conditions must be true for the `while` loop to continue executing.

```
while(guessed == false && guess_count > 0 ) {
```

Change to an AND `&&` means that if the number is guessed correctly, `guessed` will now be `true` and the `while` loop will halt after that iteration. I was not getting any errors for when the `guess_counter` dropped below zero. Try it again to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your code by replacing `||` with `&&`. Why use an extra flag variable when you have `guess_count` decrementing to check for number of guesses. The program will terminate after guessed number is equal to the input. Here is simple implementation:

```
while(guess_count-->0) {
    System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
    int input = inp.nextInt();
    if(input == number) {
        System.out.println("You guessed it right!");
        guessed = true;
        break; // The user has already guessed the number no need to guess more
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Nope!\nGuesses left: " + guess_count);
```